# Unzip and push the contents in a tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tableView which lists the contents of my document directory. I have some zip files in that. If I touch a file in the tableView, the corresponding zip file is unzipped in a temporary directory.

The problem is how to navigate the contents which I extracted in a tableView. If suppose, the extracted zip file contains folders, I should able to view them in a tableView. Actually the flow should be like a DrillDown.

I can able to extract the zip files, but problem is, have to navigate them in a tableView.
Please give me some ideas or some source codes which helps my problem.
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you some suggestions on how to solve this. The best way I can imagine is designing a table view that will continuously update its data source every time you click on an item in the list.

Let's make it clear: imagine that you have the first table view with the list of the zip files. You click on a row, you decompress the zip file to a local folder, then you push to your navigation controller a different table which will present you the contents of the unzipped file.

This new table will maintain a pointer to the parent folder (let's call it `parent`), set to `nil` at the beginning, and will contain a list of the contents of the folder you are currently in. So, this data source will show you the contents of the root folder (the one in which you decompressed the zip file), with folders and files.

When you click on a row representing a file, you will implement the appropriate logic (open the file, upload it, edit, send by email, or what else)

When you click to a row representing a folder, you should:

1. Set the data source's `parent` to the folder you are currently in (in this case the root folder)
2. Read the contents of the folder you selected
3. Update the data source's data with the content you've just read
4. Reload data in the table view (eg. `[tableView reloadData]`)

Your table view should present a button, or a dedicated row, to navigate back to the parent folder (the one contained in the `parent` parameter), so that you can go back and forth every time you want.

That solution should work fine, I think.